# using Inheritence with GUI (graphical user interfaces) in Java

Tags: java

---

I work on inheritence with GUI (graphical user interfaces)

let me explain for example I made super class which is vehicle and the subclass is car, so the code to make inheritence will be

public class Car extends Vehicle

then I want to build the class Car as JFrame like

public class Car extends JFrame implements ActionListener  {

so the problem is that I couldn't put both codes in the same class, and I need to do that.

anyone help me. thanks in advance

I wish that the question would be clear

Answer (score 1):

consider the example :

`class A extends B`

Before inheriting , think twice if `A IS A KIND OF B`, now tell me if `CAR IS A TYPE OF FRAME`?? NO?? Then do not inherit.

create a JFrame, and add car to it...

---

Better solution : 
Divide Car to Model-View-Controller classes.. and add Car's View to the Screen (`class Sceen extends JFrame`)

Now ur Car's MVC will inherit the Vehicle's MVC respectivily.! Now it makes sense : `CAR IS A VEHICLE.`

More Better :  instead of adding car's view to Screen (`AGGREGATION`) , have a function in `Screen` which gets the Car's view object and paint it in `Screen` (which is a `DEPENDENCY`). Thus achieving low coupling.!

Answer (score 1):

Java is not allowing multiple superclasses by design (and pretty good reasons.)

However, there is nothing to stop you from letting Vehichle extend JComponent(*), 
and Car extending Vehicle.

```
public class Car extends Vehicle {
...
}
```

*) JComponent is probably a better choise for the base-class, as JFrame is a rather special gui-element. A JComponent can be added to a JFrame instead.

Also, this design assumes that the primary purpose of a Vehicle (etc) is to be a
graphical representation of a vehicle. Othervise, you might consider dividing the behaviour in a VehicleViewer and Vehicle, for instance if the Vehicle actually represents a real-life vehicle, you are loading/storing Vehicles from a database etc.

Comment: BAD inheritance : vehicle extending JComponent!

Comment: Why would it be bad, if the purpose is to be an widget that is representing a vehicle?  As I wrote, if the purpose is to represent an actual vehicle (like, it has an identity), yes, then its' bad.

Answer (score 0):

Rename the Car class to CarView or reference the other Car class using it's fully qualified name, e.g. myapp.domain.Car rather than just Car.